# GEE: Indexing a List of Lists inside a property of a FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, indexing, feature-collection

I'm running the [LandTrendr algorithm](https://emapr.github.io/LT-GEE/index.html) in `GEE` over multiple points of interest, which leaves me with a `FeatureCollection` having a list of lists in one the properties for every feature.
Out if this list of lists called `LandTrendr` I need to know whether the second-to-last element of list #3, is equal to 1 (See orange arrow in the picture). How can I index/query this `LandTrendr` property to get the desired element?

I have tried many strategies to reach this index, but I don't get anyfurther than isolating the FeatureCollection to a single `Feature` having only the `LandTrendr` property left (using `.first().select(['LandTrendr'])`). At this point it refuses to convert into an array or a list using `.toList()` or `.toArray()`.

[image: FeatureCollection with List of Lists. Orange arrow indicates the desired index position to be retrieved.]

I actually wanted to share the FeatureCollection as an Asset, but somehow GEE didn't let me, so I'll be sharing the whole code below.

Code walk-through: After defining the parameters, building the input time-series, and running the algorithm, I reduce the input back to the original points of interest, as defined by [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354784/run-landtrendr-algorithm-on-a-collection-of-points-pixels-in-earth-engine). Now, the second-to-last element of list no.3 in the LandTrendr property is the desired index to be retrieved.

```
// #########################
// # Define inputs and parameters 
// #########################

//points of interest 
var myPoints = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-60,-20), {'id': 0}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(140,-20), {'id': 1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-70,10), {'id': 2}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(80,40), {'id': 3}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(10,50), {'id': 4}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(20, -10), {'id': 5})
]);

// load the LandTrendr.js module
var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js');

// define collection parameters
var startYear = 2005;
var endYear = 2016;
var startDay = '06-01'; // MM-DD start summer North Hem 
var endDay = '08-31'; // MM-DD end summer North Hem
var index = 'NDVI';
var ftvList = [];
var maskThese = ['cloud', 'shadow', 'snow'];

// define landtrendr parameters
var runParams = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};

// #################
// # Prepare Input Time-Series
// #################

// Make annual surface reflection collection 
var annualSRcol = ltgee.buildSRcollection(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, myPoints, maskThese);

// Make annual LandTrendr collection with 1-observation per year
var annualLTcol = ltgee.buildLTcollection(annualSRcol, index, ftvList);

// add preprocessed time-series to the parameters for the algorithm
runParams.timeSeries = annualLTcol; 

// ################
// # run LandTrendr
// ################
var LTresult = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr(runParams);

// Reduce the LandTrendr result by the aoi (myPoints). Use ee.Reducer.first() to select
// the pixel that intersects the point.
var ltPoints = LTresult.reduceRegions({
  collection: myPoints,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  scale: 30
});

print(ltPoints);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you want is this:

```js
ltPoints.toList(ltPoints.size())
        .map(function(feature){
               return ee.Feature(feature).getArray('LandTrendr').get([3,-2])
             })
```