# How to run BFAST Monitor over a FeatureCollection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reducers, bfast

I am working with [BFAST Monitor in Google Earth Engine](https://github.com/bfast2/geeBfastMonitor), and I would like to run the algorithm over a FeatureCollection containing individual points of interest. Like this:

```js
var norway = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', "Norway"));
var myPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(norway, 10);

var engine = require('users/andreim/geeMonitor:monitor.js');

var roi =  myPoints;//ee.Geometry.Point(-60.00, -14.33);// region of interest as a Feature
var historyStart = "2000-01-01"; // The starting date of the stable period.
var historyEnd = "2018-12-31"; // The end date of the stable period.
var monitoringStart = "2019-01-01"; // The starting date of the monitoring period.
var monitoringEnd = "2020-01-01"; // End date of monitoring period. 
var h = 0.25; //numeric scalar from interval (0,1) specifying the bandwidth relative to the sample size in MOSUM/ME monitoring processes
var period = 2; // maximum time, relative to the history period, that should be monitored. The default is 10 times the history period.
var alpha = 0.05; //Significance level of the monitoring (and ROC, if selected) procedure, i.e., probability of type I error.
var magnitudeThreshold = 0; //Threshold for magnitude level for which a change should be considered. Default is 0.
var harmonics = 1; //Order of the harmonic term.

var result = engine.bfastMonitor(roi,historyStart,historyEnd,monitoringStart,monitoringEnd,h,period,alpha,magnitudeThreshold,harmonics);
```

In mirror to [this question about LandTrendr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354784/run-landtrendr-algorithm-on-a-collection-of-points-pixels-in-earth-engine), I tried to apply a reducer over the `result`, like this:

```js
var myReduced = result.reduceRegions({
  collection: myPoints,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  scale: 30,
  tileScale : 16
});
```

But I got the error `result.reduceRegions is not a function`.

Is this a casting issue?

- By using `print(result);` I found out that the object is composed of four image collections
- By using `print(typeof(result));` I found out that `result` does not have a native GEE type, as it just returns `Object`.

So, I tried to cast `result` to a list (`ee.List(result)`) or an ImageCollection (`ee.ImageCollection(result)`) to turn the object into something that I could work with, but it kept returning the same error `___ is not a function`.

So, how do I run BFAST Monitor over a FeatureCollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the `ImageCollection` that you are interested in using the `.` operator. Then filter the `ImageCollection` to get the layer (Image) you want, e.g. the break timing:

```js
result = result.bfastResults.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", "1")).first();
```

And then your `reduceRegions` function works correctly.