# Calling js module into Google Earth Engine in R (rgee and rgeeExtra) results in 404 error

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, javascript, rgee

I want to use [BFAST Monitor in Google Earth Engine](https://github.com/bfast2/geeBfastMonitor) from within R, using [rgee](https://r-spatial.github.io/rgee/) and [rgeeExtra](https://r-earthengine.com/rgeeExtra/). Adapting code from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390812/how-to-run-bfast-monitor-over-a-featurecollection-in-gee?newreg=50d1eee534e74184829b9fac724e7d92) to rgee, I have got the following reprex:

```r
library(rgee)
library(rgeeExtra)
library(reticulate)

ee_Initialize() # initialize gee
#> ── rgee 1.1.5 ─────────────────────────────────────── earthengine-api 0.1.323 ── 
#>  ✔ user: not_defined
#>  ✔ Initializing Google Earth Engine: ✔ Initializing Google Earth Engine:  DONE!
#>  ✔ Earth Engine account: users/MathiasWeidinger 
#> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

py_install(packages=c("regex", "ee_extra", "jsbeautifier")) # install necessary python packages
#> Using virtual environment '/home/madmat/.virtualenvs/rgee' ...
#> + '/home/madmat/.virtualenvs/rgee/bin/python' -m pip install --upgrade --no-user 'regex' 'ee_extra' 'jsbeautifier'

engine <- rgeeExtra::module(x = "users/andreim/geeMonitor:monitor.js",
                            upgrade = FALSE,
                            quiet = FALSE)
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

As you can see, EE initializes successfully but calling the Earth Engine Javascript module via `rgeeExtra::module()` results in a 404 error. Considering that the source path is valid and up to date, I am pretty sure that the issue lies with the client side (i.e. me). I've tried this out with various other js modules and can confirm that all of them return 404.

Has somebody encountered similar issues and/or knows how to fix this? I am a newbie to rgeeExtra and would really love to start using js modules like the one above from within R.